# Embed Element: Could not access DOMWindow Context

Tags: java, javascript, applet, embed

I have a page with a JS Function called `test` (e.g.), and, in one page of my app I have to open a Java Applet.

In google chrome, it opens as an `embed` element, and in firefox in an `object`.

Sometimes, in my applet, I have to call my JS function to do something in the page. I doing this with:

```
applet.getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL("javascript:window.test();"));
```

In browser that use the `object`, this code work like a boss, but, if it use embed, it do nothing, trowing a exeption in Browser console, saying that the Window does not have a "test" function.

I think thi is some trouble with embed context and document context, but I dont know how to fix it, or, if it is "fixable".

So, I like to know if is there any workaround to make it work.

thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Use `deployJava.js` for writing applet elements. 2) For applets that use JS, declare `mayscript` in the applet element. 3) It is easier to debug these things if you link to a failing example. 4)  Short of a link or a great deal more information from you, I cannot see anyone else resolving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

A minor update of chrome solve it. I dont know if the problem was in Webkit or in chrome itself, but, now it works.